# Event delegation on iPhone/Android Causes Undesirable 'Click' UI Feedback

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, jquery-events

On iPhone and Android, when you click an element, the element temporarily selects and unselects to provide feedback to the user what got clicked.

However, I am using jQuery's `$("#element").on('.subelement')` method with event delegation, so I do **NOT** want `#element` to flash.... if anything I want `.subelement` to flash.

If you have an iPhone/Android you can see the effect here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RYj6X/6/embedded/result/
Clicking the button causes the whole `#container` to temporarily 'flash', which makes the button click feel 'dirty'.

Is there a way to suppress this UI feedback? Or redirect it to the element actually being clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what on god's green earth you are talking about regarding "temporarily selects" but you can use CSS to hide the native iPhone's selected color (greyish) when clicked.

```
<style>
body {-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, was using "select" as a euphamism for the visual effect produced by a "tap-highlight" since I couldn't figure out what it was actually called. Thank you, tap-highlight is exactly the thing I was looking for.